# jQuery checked radio button value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <input type="checkbox" id="check1" value="radio" />
  <label>left</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check2" value="radio2" />
  <label>right</label>
</form>
```

I would like to know if the checkbox is checked or not everytime someone clicks on it and then set a variable to the value yes.

```
if ($('#check1').attr('checked'); ){
var check1 = 'yes'; 
else 
var check1 ='no'
}
```

this is what I have so far and it doesn't work
How do I return the value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need an if-statement to do that. You can use `.is(":checked")` which will return `true` if checked and `false` if not. Assign that value directly to your variable instead of using an if-statement:

```
var check1;
$("#check1").click(function(){
   check1 = $(this).is(":checked");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
$("#check1").is(':checked')
```

Answer (score 1):

in javascript, scope is only specific to a function. unlike most other languages, this means you should not define variables inside of if or else blocks.

you should be using prop instead of attr for the checked property (assuming the latest version of jquery)

lastly, you have an erroneous semicolon which is probably breaking the if statement.

try this instead:

```
var check1;
if ($('#check1').prop('checked')) {
    check1 = 'yes'; 
} else { 
    check1 ='no'
}
```

Comment: @Matt correct. javascript does NOT scope blocks like most other languages do, only functions.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ReF4X/ Let me know if what I'm doing doesn't make sense to you.

In the future, when you have a JS problem you should make a JSfiddle and post it here. People will then revise it with a working solution.